# A book that contains, Shor's algorithm, McEliece cryptosystem, Lattice-based cryptography, Discrete logarithm

Tags: algorithm, encryption, cryptography, quantum-computing

I am looking for a book that contains descriptions of the topics: Shor's algorithm, McEliece cryptosystem, Lattice-based cryptography, Discrete logarithm; and possibly others.

Does anyone know a single book or a few that would contain there topics?

Comment: Why is this off topic?
If you close tell me why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is "Post-Quantum Cryptography" published by Daniel J. Bernstein. The book is more of a general overview and doesn't go that far into details.
It contains sections about lattice based, hash based and code based cryptography.
Shor's algorithm as well as discrete logarithm aren't handled in depth, but there is a general overview.
I think the best way to get into the details is by studying the respective scientific papers.